# Can't solve the JPQL :parameter problem by using FUNC()

Tags: java, parameters, jpql

Ok, just to cut it short, I've done the actual JPQL without using any parameter first and it looks like this.

```
SELECT count(dt) 
FROM transaction dt 
WHERE dt.transactionType = 'TEST' 
AND dt.date 
BETWEEN FUNC('TO_DATE','01-2019','mm-yyyy') 
AND FUNC('TO_DATE','02-2019','mm-yyyy')
```

This thing work! But the thing is now I need to make the transactionType and date as a parameter and this is how it looks like

```
SELECT count(dt) 
FROM transaction dt 
WHERE dt.transactionType = :transType 
AND dt.date 
BETWEEN FUNC('TO_DATE',:lastMonth,'mm-yyyy') 
AND FUNC('TO_DATE',:nextMonth,'mm-yyyy')
```

So for :transType it's fine, but inside this FUNC() seems like I shouldnt put the parameter just like that and need some workaround. I've been googling and can't find any result.

The error was like this

> You have attempted to set a parameter value using a name of
>   lastMonth,'mm-yyyy') that does not exist in the query string

As you can see, the parameter inside FUNC() take along the parameter behind it that meant for FUNC(). What did I miss? Enlighten me please.

Comment: Could you try adding a trim around your param? I think that will work then.

Comment: well I don't know abt you, but what I know even from sql, TRIM will only work with a char and not words. Or did u suggest me to put multiple trim fx around the parameter? seems unnecessary I think

Comment: Trim takes a string, it doesn't need to do anything, we just use it as marker to separate lastMonth from the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a workaround for this problem.

Initially, the simplified SQL as below:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM table tb
WHERE tb.date between to_date('01-2020','mm-yyyy') and to_date('02-2020','mm-yyyy');
```

And by directly convert the simplified SQL to JPQL, it turns out as such:

```
SELECT count(tb) 
FROM table tb 
WHERE tb.date BETWEEN FUNC('TO_DATE','01-2020','mm-yyyy') AND FUNC('TO_DATE','02-2020','mm-yyyy')
```

But, the JPQL need to be dynamic as the date will not be static, so by using JPQL parameter to ensure this JPQL can be used at any date, instinctively I thought to use as such:

```
SELECT count(tb) 
FROM table tb 
WHERE tb.date BETWEEN FUNC('TO_DATE',:fromDate,'mm-yyyy') AND FUNC('TO_DATE',:toDate,'mm-yyyy')
```

But as my initial question when this thread first started, such JPQL will not work. So how did I found a workaround? Relatively quite simple actually.

Instead of using this to get the ranging date (as from sql wise I use to_date)

```
WHERE tb.date BETWEEN FUNC('TO_DATE','','') AND FUNC('TO_DATE','','')
```

I used this

```
WHERE FUNC('TO_CHAR','','') between (--fromDate) and (--toDate)
```

Which finally resulted in final working JPQL of

```
SELECT count(tb) 
FROM table tb 
WHERE FUNC('TO_CHAR',tb.date,'mm-yyyy') BETWEEN (:fromDate) AND (:toDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using setString for the parameter type.

I always had difficulty with named parameters within JPA, depending upon how the query was created - try using ordinal parameters, eg: ?1  and set them by index.

I'd avoid FUNC as it can carry some major overhead if you're not extremely careful.

Comment: setString for the parameter type? I don't even start at that yet, since right now I'm on a certain application that allow me to test jpql directly (as long as your code is correct which in this case, I messed up at FUNC with the parameters). Positional parameters? Ordinal param u mean? If my requirement fit that criteria, I don't even bother to seek till this FUNC(). But due to the circumstance, I need it.

Comment: Yes, ordinal parameters - I'll correct my initial statement.

I'll repeat - be careful with func as it makes callbacks into the Java and the column won't be considered if you're relying on it for index selection.  I've had bad experiences with it forcing the Db optimizer into serial scanning of tables.